# Return record from Ballerina resource function

Tags: http, service, ballerina

Please consider the following Ballerina service.

```
import ballerina/http;

public type Tool readonly & record {|
    string name;
    string api_path;
    ToolInput[] inputs;
|};

public type ToolInput readonly & record {|
    string name;
    boolean required;
    any default_value = ();
    any[] allowed_values = ["any"];
|};


public final table<Tool> key(name) toolsTable = table [
    {
        name: "deploy", 
        api_path: "deploy", 
        inputs: [
            {name: "environment", required: true},
            {name: "service", required: true},
            {name: "version", required: false, default_value: "master"},
            {name: "version_type", required: false, default_value: "branch", allowed_values: ["branch", "commit_id", "build_number"]}        
        ]
    }
];

service /foo on new http:Listener(9090) {

    resource function get list\-tools() returns Tool[] {
        return toolsTable.toArray();
    }   
}
```

When returning the `Tool[]` array from the resource function, we are getting the error `invalid resource method return type: expected anydata|http:Response|http:StatusCodeResponse|error, but found Tool[]`.

What are the restrictions when returning a Ballerina record from a resource function?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioend in the error message, we can only return a type that belongs to one of `anydata`, `http:Response`, `http:StatusCodeResponse` or `error`. According to the above example the return type `Tool[]` should belong to `anydata` But `Tool` record contains two fields where the type is `any`. Because of this reason, `Tool[]` does not belong to `anydata`. Simply we can change the type of these fields into `anydata` as shown below.

```
import ballerina/http;

public type Tool readonly & record {|
    string name;
    string api_path;
    ToolInput[] inputs;
|};

public type ToolInput readonly & record {|
    string name;
    boolean required;
    anydata default_value = ();
    anydata[] allowed_values = ["any"];
|};


public final table<Tool> key(name) toolsTable = table [
    {
        name: "deploy", 
        api_path: "deploy", 
        inputs: [
            {name: "environment", required: true},
            {name: "service", required: true},
            {name: "version", required: false, default_value: "master"},
            {name: "version_type", required: false, default_value: "branch", allowed_values: ["branch", "commit_id", "build_number"]}        
        ]
    }
];

service /foo on new http:Listener(9090) {

    resource function get list\-tools() returns Tool[] {
        return toolsTable.toArray();
    }   
}
```